# Python way of polling longrunning operations from operation name in Google Cloud?

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm calling a Google Cloud Function that returns an `Operation` object implementing the `google.longrunning.Operations` interface. I want to poll this operation from another Python process that will only receive the operation name (will not have access to the operation object itself). So I need something like:

```
operation = getOperation(operationName)
isdone = operation.done()
```

AFAIK, you can't do the first step above. I haven't found it here: https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core/operation.html

I would like to do what is explained in the docs about the `google.longrunning` interface (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.longrunning#google.longrunning.Operations.GetOperation):

```
rpc GetOperation(GetOperationRequest) returns (Operation)
```

Where the `GetOperationRequest` simply requires the operation name. Is there a way to "re-create" an operation using functions from the `google-cloud-python` library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`get_operation`](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core/operations_client.html#google.api_core.operations_v1.OperationsClient.get_operation) method of the ["Long-Running Operations Client"](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core/operations_client.html#module-google.api_core.operations_v1):

```
from google.api_core import operations_v1
api = operations_v1.OperationsClient()
name = ...
response = api.get_operation(name)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm using `ImageAnnotatorClient`, calling `async_batch_annotate_files`. What's the gRPC Channel that I need to use in order to instantiate the `OperationsClient()`?. It seems like passing a gRPC Channel to the ImageAnnotatorClient is deprecated (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/vision/gapic/v1p2beta1/api.html). Thanks again!

Comment: If your client is `ia_client = ImageAnnotatorClient(...)`, can you try `OperationsClient(ia_client.transport)`?

Answer (score 1):

Update for more recent clients. You need to refresh the operation using the OperationClient:

For updating an existing operation you will need to pass the channel across to the OperationClient.

For example, backing up a Firestore datastore.

```
from google.cloud import firestore_admin_v1
from google.api_core import operations_v1, grpc_helpers
import time

def main():

    client = firestore_admin_v1.FirestoreAdminClient()
    channel = grpc_helpers.create_channel(client.SERVICE_ADDRESS)
    api = operations_v1.OperationsClient(channel)

    db_path = client.database_path('myproject', 'mydb')
    operation = client.export_documents(db_path)

    current_status = api.get_operation(operation.name)

    while current_status.done == False:

       time.sleep(5)
       current_status = api.get_operation(operation.name)
       print('waiting to complete')

    print('operation done')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, The AutoML Tables Client didn't have a `SERVICE_ADDRESS` or `SCOPE` properties, so I can't create a new gRPC channel.

But using the existing one in the client seems to work!

```
from google.api_core import operations_v1
from google.cloud.automl_v1beta1 import TablesClient

automl_tables_client = TablesClient(
    credentials=...,
    project=...,
    region=...,
)

operation_name = ""

grpc_channel = automl_tables_client.auto_ml_client.transport._channel
api_client = operations_v1.OperationsClient(grpc_channel)
response = api_client.get_operation(operation_name)
```