# How to get cloud speech api response in python if I only have the operation name?

Tags: python-3.x, google-speech-api

I am sending a long speech recognition file for speech recognition.

```
operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
operation_name = operation._operation.name
```

There is another file where I have to use `operation_name` (returned by google speech API) to get back the response again.

ref: [Python way of polling longrunning operations from operation name in Google Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317626/python-way-of-polling-longrunning-operations-from-operation-name-in-google-cloud)

I tried `get_operation` method of the "Long-Running Operations Client":

```
from google.api_core import operations_v1
api = operations_v1.OperationsClient()
name = ...
response = api.get_operation(name)
```

but I get the following error for the line:

> api = operations_v1.OperationsClient()
>
> TypeError: init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'channel'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer on Github issues:

```
from google.cloud import speech
client = speech.SpeechClient()

from google.api_core import operations_v1
api = operations_v1.OperationsClient(client.transport.channel)
name = ...
response = api.get_operation(name)
```

reference : [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/2361)