# How do I poll Google Long-Running Operations using Python Library?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have a [google.api_core.operation.Operation](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/operation.html) object from

```
operation = client.async_batch_annotate_files(requests=[async_request])
```

I would like to check the status of that operation. I'm trying to use [google.api_core.operations_v1.AbstractOperationsClient](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/operations_client.html). It has the method, `get_operation`, which should return the status.

```
client=AbstractOperationsClient()
res=client.get_operation(operation.operation.name)
```

I get an error when that is run:

```
ValueError: Request {'name': '*redacted*'} does not match any URL path template in available HttpRule's ['/v1/{name=operations/**}']
```

The error is generated with [this code](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/_modules/google/api_core/path_template.html), I believe.

Comment: I've not tried this and I'm too lazy to write a repro but, I suspect you're trying to using the service-specific operation name and you need to provide the global|long name so that the  generic API can determine which service you intend. The [Operation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Operation) document (see `name`) suggests `operations/{unique_id}` which matches the error `v1/{name=operations/**`. `unique_id` is confusing because `unique_id` is not documented elsehwere in the page but I *suspect* it may match the `metadata.id`.

Comment: I suggest (!) you try `/v1/name=operations/{ID}` where `ID` is the `metadata.id`. The `**` is a wildcard and so you should be able to use that format with a list operation method to test.

Comment: For completeness. The `operation` return supports a sync `operation.result()` and async `operation.add_done_callback()` if you simply want to await completion rahther than poll

Comment: Thanks, @DazWilkin. the format `operations/{unique_id}` got me past that HttpRule error. It just says that the operation doesn't exist/I don't have access now. I don't think I have the right id. `metadata.id` is empty. I'm trying the list operation method but I don't think I have the right permissions in my enterprise. I'll keep playing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I could get working is using the `OperationsClient` that is implemented and exposed by the Vision API `ImageAnnotatorClient` (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68834896/16929894) in another thread):

```python
ops_client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient().transport.operations_client
```

Using this client works when passing the full operation name, which was giving you the initial error about URL templates:

```python
ops_client.get_operation(vision_operation.operation.name)
```

Querying `get_operation()` gives you the expected metadata of the operation, such as the `done` status to detect when the operation finishes:

```python
ops_client.get_operation(vision_operation.operation.name).done
# Output
False
```

Otherwise, if you need a simpler way of querying status, the `running()` method of the Vision API Operation object returns a simple `True` or `False` depending on completion status. You don't have to instantiate an `OperationsClient` this way.

```
vision_operation.running()
```

Full snippet (Based off [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/samples/vision-async-batch-annotate-images) guide):

```python
def main():
    input_image_uri="gs://cloud-samples-data/vision/label/wakeupcat.jpg"
    output_uri=<destination_bucket>

    ops_client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient().transport.operations_client

    # get_vision_op() not included for simplicity, returns the Operation out of async_batch_annotate_images() as shown on the linked guide
    vision_operation = get_vision_op(input_image_uri, output_uri)

    print(ops_client.get_operation(vision_operation.operation.name).done)
    print(vision_operation.running())

    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
    response = vision_operation.result(90)

    print(vision_operation.running())
    print(ops_client.get_operation(vision_operation.operation.name).done)
    # Output sent to destination bucket
    gcs_output_uri = response.output_config.gcs_destination.uri
    print("Output written to GCS")
```