# Get dataproc operation in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-sdk

Having an operation_id from a long running operation (starting Dataproc cluster), I'm trying to get the operation instance to call `operation.result()` on it in Python.

First looking at the Rest reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.operations/get), the generated GET request works as expected:

```
curl \
  'https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/regions/europe-west6/operations/some-operation-id?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

Also calling gcloud on the command line returns the operation correctly:

```
gcloud dataproc operations describe some-operation-id
```

Now I'm failing to replicate the same in Python. Here's what I've tried:

```
client_options = ClientOptions(
    api_endpoint=f"dataproc.googleapis.com",
)

client = AbstractOperationsClient(client_options=client_options)

operation = client.get_operation(name="projects/myproject/regions/europe-west6/operations/some-operation-id")
```

This raises an error:

> ValueError: Request {'name':
> 'projects/myproject/regions/europe-west6/operations/some-operation-id'}
> does not match any URL path template in available HttpRule's
> ['/v1/{name=operations/**}']

It looks like the path template is wrong, it only accepts something with operations/... so I've tried to omit the project and the region:

```
operation = client.get_operation(name="operations/some-operation-id")
```

Which gets me past that error but then can not find the URL:

> google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET
> https://dataproc.googleapis.com:443/v1/operations/some-operation-id

So my question is, how do I need to call client.get_operation to get the operation if I only have the project, region and operation_id ?

Comment: You should not need to set `ClientOptions` since you're using the default endpoint. You're using the incorrect value. The correct value is `https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/` (possibly without the `https://` prefix). Just drop `ClientOptions`. Then it should work with the full (!) `projects/.../regions/.../operations/...` path.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that doesn't work. If I drop the `ClientOptions` and use the full path, I get that same error (Request ... does not match any URL path...). If I use `api_endpoint=f"dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/"` with the shorter path `operations/...` I get an error that the url `/v1/:443/v1/operations/.../` was not found, so this messes up the endpoint completely.

Comment: Oh boy! This was not obvious. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve this albeit using `OperationsClient` (not `AbstractOperationsClient`):

```py
import os

from google.api_core import client_options,operations_v1
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1

project = os.getenv("PROJECT")
region = os.getenv("REGION")
cluster = os.getenv("CLUSTER")


api_endpoint = f"{region}-dataproc.googleapis.com:443"

options = client_options.ClientOptions(
    api_endpoint=api_endpoint,
)

client = dataproc_v1.ClusterControllerClient(
        client_options=options,
)

# See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317626
client = operations_v1.OperationsClient(client._transport._grpc_channel)

name=f"projects/{project}/regions/{region}/operations"

resp = client.list_operations(
    name=name,
    filter_="{}",
)

# Either
# print(list(resp))
# Or
for foo in resp:
    print(foo)

# With a specific operation ID
operation="..."
name=f"projects/{project}/regions/{region}/operations/{operation}"

resp = client.get_operation(name=name)
print(resp)
```

One tool that I used to ensure (we) were on the correct path was to append `--log-http` to the `gcloud` command:

```bash
gcloud dataproc operations list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--region=${REGION} \
--log-http
```

Yielding:

```
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project}/regions/{region}/operations?alt=json&filter=%7B%7D&pageSize=100
```